# What is the correct way to read a MIME encoded stream?

Tags: java, tcp, stream, mime

I have a TCP socket with streaming MIME messages on it. I can use the JavaMail API to parse one MIME message at a time by searching for the boundary, then looking for the boundary + -- symbol.

This seems like a lot of String manipulation. Someone out there has to have done MIME-encoded streaming correctly in Java. Where is it hiding?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library:

http://code.google.com/p/mimeparser/